# SiriKit with VoIP call Application not working in iOS 10

Tags: iphone, xcode, voip, ios10, sirikit

I am doing VoIP call Application. There i can make call through my application. I have integrated SiriKit setup and added following code.

```
#pragma mark -Start Audio Call
- (void)resolveContactsForStartAudioCall:(INStartAudioCallIntent *)intent
                          withCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray<INPersonResolutionResult *> *resolutionResults))completion{
    NSLog(@"maytest resolveContactsForStartAudioCall");


    NSArray<INPerson *> *recipients = intent.contacts;

    NSMutableArray<INPersonResolutionResult *> *resolutionResults = [NSMutableArray array];



    if (recipients.count == 0) {

        completion(@[[INPersonResolutionResult needsValue]]);
        return;
    }else if(recipients.count==1){
        [resolutionResults addObject:[INPersonResolutionResult successWithResolvedPerson:recipients.firstObject]];
    }else if(recipients.count>1){
        [resolutionResults addObject:[INPersonResolutionResult disambiguationWithPeopleToDisambiguate:recipients]];
    }else{
        [resolutionResults addObject:[INPersonResolutionResult unsupported]];

    }
    completion(resolutionResults);
}

- (void)confirmStartAudioCall:(INStartAudioCallIntent *)intent
                   completion:(void (^)(INStartAudioCallIntentResponse *response))completion{

    NSUserActivity *userActivity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:NSStringFromClass([INStartAudioCallIntent class])];
    INStartAudioCallIntentResponse *response = [[INStartAudioCallIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:INStartAudioCallIntentResponseCodeReady userActivity:userActivity];
    completion(response);
}

- (void)handleStartAudioCall:(INStartAudioCallIntent *)intent
                  completion:(void (^)(INStartAudioCallIntentResponse *response))completion{
    NSUserActivity *userActivity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:NSStringFromClass([INStartAudioCallIntent class])];

    INStartAudioCallIntentResponse *response = [[INStartAudioCallIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:INStartAudioCallIntentResponseCodeContinueInApp userActivity:userActivity];
    completion(response);
}
```

But, its not making calls through my app. Its making calls through native dialer and some times showing application not yet set up with siri.
Could anyone guide me and after make call, how to save call history.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you setup intents correctly? Siri needs to know that your app supports calling via SiriKit before it can route it to the above delegate methods. Check the Apple Sample Code at: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem too!!!

I my case, it's because I'm calling Siri in Chinese!!!! It takes me a half day to figure it out!!

If I change Siri language to English and everything works just fine!

In Chinese Siri will only call through native dialer no matter how I specify the application.

I'm not sure if it happens on other languages too since I can only test those two.